# Sticky header in table (div)

Tags: jquery, css, css-tables, fixed-header-tables

URL [ **http: //  androidplus.ml/demo/time-table/** ]

I created a simple time table and i would like to days of the week (header) are always visible - command fixed.

I've tried with jquery.sticky.js but without correctly effect.

[image: Screenshot]

The first row is extended ... I don't know why:

[image: Screenshot2 (gif)]

I would like the header was hidden in a table. However, I do not know how to do it . I've tried a lot of ideas - nothing

Please help.

Something like this: 
**http: // www.matts411.com/static/demos/grid/index.html**
...

HTML:

```
<div class="content">

        <div class="table">
<div class="days">
    <div class="cell headr hb">PON<div></div></div>
    <div class="cell headr">WT<div></div></div>
    <div class="cell headr hb">ŚRO<div></div></div>
    <div class="cell headr">CZW<div></div></div>
    <div class="cell headr hb">PI<div></div></div>
</div>

 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">MATMA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">ANGIELSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">WF</div>
    <div class="cell">WF</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">MATEMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">MATEMATYKA</div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">MATEMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">ANGIELSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">NIEMIECKI</div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">GEOGRAFIA</div>
    <div class="cell">ANGIELSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">GEOGRAFIA</div>
    <div class="cell">MATEMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">ANGIELSKI</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">MATEMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">ANGIELSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">MATEMATYKA</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell ca">INFORMATYKA</div>
    <div class="cell">BIOLOGIA</div>
    <div class="cell ca">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell">POLSKI</div>
    <div class="cell ca">BIOLOGIA</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
     .content {
height: auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    min-width: 211px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.row { display: table-row; }
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    background: #3B3737;
    font-size: 11px;
    min-width: 100px;
}
.headr {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #A83622 !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #312929;

}
.days{
    display: table-row;
}
.ca{
    background: #312E2E;
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Done. I post url where is this time table but ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all the rows in another div instead of everything in div.table and set overflow scroll for that div alone and margin-top:height of header.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the `position: absolute` property in your CSS. This will make any element "stick" in place.